# I need some help understanding OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently working on a board game using java, and I got a question about how exactly OOP works in this situation:

Right now, I have two objects:

1. Game board object
2. Win object that takes in the game board object in its constructor

Both objects have been instantiated at the start of my main method.

The game board object will be the active one with all the pieces moving back and forth and being destroyed.

Every time a move is done, the Win object will check whether the current player has won the game or not.

Now, the question is:

> Will the board object that is passed into the Win object at the
>   beginning update as the active board object in the main method?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    Win w = new Win(m);
```

Comment: Well i think a simple answer to your question is... try it out :P.

Comment: Yes it will update. Not sure why you need the Win object though. I think in this case it would be best to ask the board if there is a winner or maybe who it is rather than this approach. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It's funny how I post something, and after a few seconds, I think of a way to answer the problem myself and actually answers it. But thank you guys anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't even an OOP question, this is basic java. because java stores references to objects in the memory (pointers, this is why it's called NullPointer), if you have Object A and B referring to the same memory place, and you update A-s value, B-s value will get updated too.

When you copy an object in a another one (Object A = B), then you only copy a memory address.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That explanation was very helpful. But I think I'm still a little confused about the difference between basic Java language and OOP. Is there are a big difference between the two? I thought Java itself is an object oriented programming language.

Comment: @JasonJ.Y.Kim Java is just an object-oriented programming language. You can do OOP in C++ or Python or many other languages.

Comment: @Jason J.Y. Kim When I say "basic java", I speak about the core language, without any fancy things like built-in libraries or proper OOP. You can read it like "This question does not relate directly to OOP functionality of java"

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score -1):

Win is not an object!  win is an action a.k.a a method!  Some objects for your game:

- Game
- Board
- Player
- Console

Comment: Well, um... technically, it's an object instantiation of a class named Win.

Comment: Hm? Did you want tobsay "Win should be a method"? Also, Console? Why? Just why?

Comment: Of course you can create a class called Walk and instantiate it into an object, but from the OOP perspective objects are not actions!

Comment: @Igor Zelaya Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes, win should be a method of the player object.